# About the use of GDP and GDP squared in econometric analysis

Tags: multiple-regression, econometrics

I have found many econometric studies on the Environmental Kuznets Curve (EKC)* include time-series of 1) GDP, 2) GDP squared, and 3) environmental quality proxy (e.g. CO$_2$ emissions).

Environmental quality proxy is the dependent variable, GDP and GDP squared are the explanatory variables.

However, **aren't GDP and GDP squared dependent on each other? I thought explanatory variables in econometric analysis should be independent of each other.**

*EKC is a hypothesized relationship between environmental quality and economic development: various indicators of environmental degradation tend to get worse as modern economic growth occurs until average income reaches a certain point over the course of development.

Comment: Are you mixing up linear and nonlinear dependence for covariates (not parameters)?

Comment: Sorry, I have elaborated the question and corrected the misused terms.

Comment: I have great difficulties conceiving of any economic analysis that could employ independent explanatory variables, because in economic studies all variables are beyond the control of the experimenter--they are observed--and, as such, will be subject to many dependencies.  If you really need to use *orthogonal* variables in your regression, then simply regress GDP squared against GDP and replace GDP squared by the residuals in your model.

Comment: If I disagree with @whuber I usually turn out to be wrong but in this territory accidents of personal history may let me know what you mean.  As I recall this curve is taken to be (approximately) quadratic -- with the interesting and important detail of a turning point within the range of the data -- so fitting a function in the predictor and its square makes sense. But surely it is not GDP but something more like GDP per head??? The dependence of one on the other doesn't bite in this application.

Comment: To elaborate on my earlier comment, you can't have exact *linear* dependence, say $x$ and $3 \cdot x$, because otherwise the regression formula cannot be calculated. But $x$ and $x^2$ are not linearly dependent, so this is not a problem. Regressors are usually correlated in observational data, and this is not a problem, provided you have enough data to have enough non-overlapping variation.

Comment: @Nick I see no disagreement between us, so I probably wasn't sufficiently clear.  My point is that independence of regressors is not a requirement of linear regression. If, for technical numerical reasons, one wants to use orthogonal regressors, then a quadratic term can be introduced through the Gram-Schmidt process (*aka* "orthogonal polynomials").